# why are files being displayed in red with an *

Tags: unix, vim

i recently had to move the location of my dropbox, which is where I keep all my code.  now that I've moved everything, all my files are showing in the terminal in red color with an * at the end of the file, what does this mean ?

[image: inside vim]

[image: and at the command line]

Comment: depends on syntax highlighting rules.  Do an `ls -l ` on them  i am guessing it is cause somehow they are marked as executable

Comment: I was going to guess symlinks

Comment: @Doon yes, those files are executable, I just changed my dropbox location and the mode's on all the files udpdated, so mostly everything in dropbox is -rwxr-xr-x  I'm not sure if this represents a problem or not, thoughts ?

Comment: it doesn't matter too much if they are 755,  just that if you where to try to execute them , they probably won't work. not sure why they  all got +x ,  did you access/touch them on a non *nix system (Such as windows?)

Comment: so when I changed the location of dropbox, all my git repo's said that files were changed from 644 to 755, i'm not entirely sure what happened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ls -lrt o/p (one of the listing method in unix)

```
- /: directories
- @: symbolic links
- |: FIFOs
- =: sockets
- *: executable files
```

In my case where I have AMD processor GPU I got similar issue. Later found that 'ls' command libraries mark them * for my all files on which I ws having executable rights

say You have a sale ** conditions apply

Kind of same thing.. files which are actually executable with 777 (or permissions which allows me executable rights) permissions on a file but if I do ./filename OS libraries says there is something hidden or not known.
I checked Super User section there I became Conscious.

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to make much contextual sense, my level might be too low.

Comment: actually during listing unix uses `ls` command so supported libraries packages for `ls` are loaded for certain platform (in my case I have thosiba Laptop with AMD64 GPU processor and acrhitecture is little diferent & OS is Linux mint same happens) as kernal calls with systems find some addtional info so it marks* to files

Comment: actually there is no need to worry you can work as normal avoiding *

Comment: its like you pour water in different vessels .. representation affects but end result is its just water :P

Comment: The problem for me was same was rectfied by seeing that question

Comment: @FDinoff: See I updated answer with my understanding

Answer (score 0):

The `*` signals that the **files are executable**. Somehow during your file system operations, the execute flag (the `x` in the `rwx------` output of `ls -l`) got set. This can happen when you move across different file system types (e.g. to an USB thumb drive, or a Samba share, maybe also due to Dropbox).

Both Vim's *NERDTree* plugin (which you use in the screenshot) and the shell's `ls` command have highlighting rules that emphasizes executable files (I guess you don't want to change that.)

### Remedy

To remove the flag, run (in the shell)

```
$ chmod -x file1 file2 path/to/another/file ...
```